# SSSD ignoring ldap_access_filter

Tags: ldap, sssd

I've setup sssd and LDAP.  Users authenticate and login.  My problem is that sssd seems to ignore the ldap_access_filter option and allows all users to login.  I've examined the logs/debug and pam_sss authorizes the users every time regardless of the filter (I've tried a couple different ones all with the same result).

This is the command used to configure the system:

```
authconfig 
    --updateall --passalgo=md5 --enableldap --enableldapauth  \
    --ldapserver=ldaps://ldap.example.com  \
    --ldapbase=ou=people,dc=example,dc=com \
    --enableldaptls --enableldapstarttls --disablekrb5 \
    --ldaploadcacert=http://certserver/cacerts/cacert.pem \
    --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enableshadow \ 
    --enablecachecreds --enablemkhomedir
```

This is the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[domain/default]
debug_level = 9
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
cache_credentials = True
ldap_search_base = ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=sysadmins,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.example.com
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2

domains = default
[nss]

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]
```

The pam.d/system-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Example /var/log/secure:

```
Dec 30 17:40:36 test login: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=testacct
Dec 30 17:40:36 test login: pam_sss(login:auth): authentication success; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost= user=testacct
Dec 30 17:40:36 test login: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user testacct by LOGIN(uid=0)
Dec 30 17:40:36 test login: LOGIN ON tty1 BY testacct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you're not specifying an actual filter. You have to understand what a "filter" is, according to LDAP and SSSD. Here's my own sssd.conf with the filters.

My LDAP access filter is saying if the person logging in has host=servername or host=ALL, they can access that machine.

```
[domain/default]

ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=net?sub?|(host=palaceredirect.example.net)(host=ALL)
ldap_group_search_base = ou=Group,dc=example,dc=net
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldap://library.example.net
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
access_provider = ldap
ldap_access_filter = (|(host=palaceredirect.example.net)(host=ALL))
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
enumerate = True
autofs_provider = ldap

[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo, autofs

domains = default

[nss]

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]
```

You can ignore my search base. The point of that was to allow "enumerate = True" to work effectively for getent passwd.

Answer (score 4):

While I've always used /etc/security/access.conf to control server logon access, according to the doco (and Sokel's working example) you're possibly missing the "access_provider=ldap" line in sssd.conf.

Comment: +1 for identifying the missing `access_provider=ldap` configuration option

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following as it worked for me for a centos based distro

```
access_provider = ldap
ldap_access_order = filter
ldap_group_member = member
ldap_access_filter = (memberOf=cn=vpn-clients,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com)
```